# Qt - SelectedItems in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm trying to return a vector of selected rows from a QTableView widget(snippet copied below), however the values returned do not correspond to the selection and I believe I've not understood QModelIndexList/QModelIndex with respect to QTableView. Can you let me know where I'm wrong or the right way to access selected items from a QTableView?
C_model is of type QStandardItemModel

```
for(int i = 0; i < c_model->rowCount(); i++)
  {
    if (selectionModel->isRowSelected(i, QModelIndex()))
    {
      QStringList selection;
      std::vector<std::string> currentIndexValues;
      for (int j = 0; j < c_model->columnCount(); j++)
      {
        QVariant q = c_model->data(c_model->index(i, j));
        selection.append(q.toString());

        currentIndexValues.push_back(q.toString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
        printf(" %s\t ", currentIndexValues[j].c_str());
      }
      printf("\n");
      v_selectedItems.push_back(currentIndexValues);
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QAbstractItemView` (the base class of `QTableView`) offers a `QItemSelectionModel` for this purpose. You can access that model via [QTableView::itemSelectionModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel)  and then retrieve the selected rows via [QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows):

```
QModelIndexList selectedRows = yourTableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();

foreach( QModelIndex index, selectedRows )
{
    int row = index.row();
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach before resorting to go over the entire rows/columns in the table. The table is sorted on the first column - Can this be the reason why the selections are incoherent? 
`foreach(QModelIndex index, indexes)
  {
    int row = index.row();
    int column = index.column();
    for(int j = 0; j < c_model->columnCount(); j++)
    {
      QVariant q = c_model->data(c_model->index(row,j+column));
      printf(" %s\t ", q.toString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
    }
    printf("\n");
  }`

Comment: SelectedRows definitely reduces the lines of code and I now am able to read the entire row using the following
`v_selectedItems.clear();
  foreach(QModelIndex index, indexes)
  {
    std::vector<std::string> l_row;
    for(int l = 0; l < c_model->columnCount(); l++)
      l_row.push_back(index.sibling(index.row(),l).data().toString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
    v_selectedItems.push_back(l_row);
`